# reference auto-increment columns?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables that I am working with that use the same column; one table contains the text and the other table contains the images; they use the column listing_id so that the right text shows up with the right images;

my problem is that because column listing_id is auto-increment, my first table is able to have an insert into query that is able to insert the text and then +1 the column listing_id; however the 2nd table I use another INSERT INTO query will not have the right listing_id,

because some entries for listing_id have been deleted, meaning that the 2nd table's listing_id will always be behind the 1st tables listing_id;

how do I reference the column listing_id?

Comment: If you always have both text and an image, you can combine them into a single table, which will make your life a lot easier!

Comment: Not a good idea if you want to have a normalized database.  He says imageS, which means there could be 1000 images for the entry in the first table, not just one to be maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an INT column called something like "parent_id" in the dependant tables that stores the id of the main table that it is referencing.  When you select records from the first, you would then JOIN the tables with the auto_increment field of the first field against the "parent_id" of the second.

As MrSlayer mentions, use the newly inserted ID of the first table to update "parent_id".  You *should* typically have a unique ID field in the second table for uniqueness, but it shouldn't be part of the relationship to the first table.

If you're unclear about how to get the id that the first table auto_increments to when you insert, use [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1 ...");
echo "Last inserted record_id in table1 was " .  mysql_insert_id();

INSERT INTO table1 (mytextcolumn) VALUES('text');
INSERT INTO table2 (parent_id,image_name) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'someimage.png');
```

Comment: or `myslqi_insert_id()` if you are using the `MySQLi` interface as you should or `$db->insert_id` in Oo style

Comment: True...however you are doing the insert, get the I'd it used, and use it in parent_id when adding to the following tables

Comment: @GDP I don't see a clear example is the code like this  "$somevar" mysql_insert_id(), will the $somevar store the last id?

Comment: Updated my answer with an example to use.  At the echo, you have the auto_incremented id, which you would then use to update "parent_id" when you INSERT records into the other table(s)

Comment: but yes, you can  use $somevar = mysql_insert_id();

Comment: @GDP, sorry you missed my point.  Yes, I agree with your approach, but not with your recommending the use of the `MySQL` interface.  Always use the `MySQLi` interface if it is available -- as it always is with current systems.

Comment: There are plenty of folks that make that point - my world consists of 100+ websites of legacy code, so that's the world I live in, sorry.